# Convert function into string

Tags: r

I have defined a variable which is a list of function.

```
var_function <- mean
```

I could use any functions. How could I convert function `mean` into a string? Thanks for any suggestion. Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: I guess the only thing that is unclear is whether you want the definition of `mean` as a character or do you want the name of the function (i.e. `"mean"`) as a character?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can turn any function into a line-by-line character vector with `deparse()`.

```
deparse(setNames)
# [1] "function (object = nm, nm) "
# [2] "{"                          
# [3] "    names(object) <- nm"    
# [4] "    object"                 
# [5] "}"
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was looking for a quick way to convert a function into a string, and this led me to `paste0(deparse(fun), collapse = " ")`

Comment: `deparse()` works well for this particular question, in which `var_function` is fed as a variable. If it is fed as a string, however, (`"var_function"`), then `deparse(get())` can be used: `deparse(get("var_function"))`.

Answer (score 11):

As of R 4.0, there is also `deparse1()`.  This will return the function as a single string.

```
f <- function(x) {
  x + 2
}

strf <- deparse1(f)

strf
#> [1] "function (x)  {     x + 2 }"
```

To get the function string back to a real function, use `eval()` with `str2lang()`:

```
f2 <- eval(str2lang(strf))

f2(4)

#> 6
```